# how to add a timestamp into a file

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

im trying to add a time stamp into the attachment file. I tried to do it using new Date.getTime but that does not seem to work

```
function init(cash){
    try {
        cash = getFullNumber(cash);
        if(cash <= 0) return;
        var userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(client.config.dataFolder + "/users/" + currentUser + ".json", "utf8"));
        var arr = getMaxItems(userData, cash);
        if(arr){
            if(arr.length==0){
                client.users.get(currentUser).send("You Need More Cash!");
            } else {
                var text = ahk(arr);
                var file = client.config.dataFolder + "/ahks/" + getFileName();
                fs.writeFileSync(file, text);
                client.users.get(currentUser).send({
                      files: [{
                          //attachment: 'C:/Bot/Currently Running/Cafe Team Bot ver 2.3.0/test.ahk',
                        attachment: file,
                        name: 'opt.ahk'
                      }]
                    });
            }
        }
        //if(str.length>0)
            //client.users.get(currentUser).send(str + "\n`++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++`");
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use new Date() or Date.now() for unix timestamp

Comment: Where are you trying to add the timestamp? I don't see any Date objects in your code.

Comment: .users.get(currentUser).send({
                      files: [{
                          //attachment: 'C:/Bot/Currently Running/Cafe Team Bot ver 2.3.0/test.ahk',
                        attachment: file,
                        name: 'opt.ahk'
                      }]

im trying to put it were it says "opt.ahk" id rather the date in place of the filename